# Save object of LocalDate (Java.time) in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class (say `Class A`) which has a field `LocalDate localDate` (Java.time), I have considered using `LocalDate` as I want to save the 'date' without 'time'. I want to save an object of this class A to firebase database. As `LocalDate` is `serializable` I thought I will easily be able to save it on the FB Database but while actually implementing it, I got this error:

```
'firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found conflicting getters for name: getChronology'
```

I posted this on twitter and got a quick response from @puf and doug.

[image]
[image]

I did get some help but I'm still looking for answer to a couple of questions:

1. Is there an easy and a generic way somehow to keep the field in my model as `LocalDate` and yet just use it as `String` while storing in database? Something like `overriding` the `toString()` method (though overriding `toString()` wont work here as Firebase does not use serializable to get object data).
2. What would be the best solution to "How to save date without time to Firebase Database"?

Answer (score 3):

As I implied in my followup tweet, it's in your best interest to:

1. Use a plain long value to represent a point in time
2. Defer the use of LocalDate (or whatever derived object) to other parts of your application that actually need its date manipulation abilities.

The reasons for this are:

1. Storing times as a long means you have the ability to sort and filter your database queries by that single value.
2. You don't have to mangle your POJO to provide getters and setters that try to convert a `long` date to that derived object, without even know if it's going to be used.  It's simpler and more efficient to delay as needed.

The bottom line is that it's easier, more flexible, and more efficient NOT to use a utility class with data models. Data models work better with Firebase when they contain the raw data stored.

Note that with Firestore, there is special handling for native Date object types on most platforms.  So if you ever want to port to Firestore, it's actually better to use your platform's date type to read and write Firestore timestamp fields.

Comment: But if you really don't have an option, you can always write your own serializers and deserializers that convert your java objects to Map objects that can be used to interact with Firebase.  Prepare to write a lot of code in that case.